# Python: Match strings for certain terms

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of tweets, from which I have to choose tweets that have terms like "sale", "discount", or "offer". Also, I need to find tweets that advertise certain deals, like a discount, by recognizing things like "%", "Rs.", "$" amongst others. I have absolutely no idea about regular expressions and the documentation isn't getting me anywhere. Here is my code. It's rather lousy, but please excuse that

```
import pymongo
import re
import datetime
client  = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client .PWSocial
fourteen_days_ago = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=14)
id_list = [57947109, 183093247, 89443197, 431336956]
ar1 = [" deal "," deals ", " offer "," offers " "discount", "promotion", " sale ", " inr", " rs", "%", "inr ", "rs ", " rs."]
def func(ac_id):
    mylist = []
    newlist = []
    tweets = list(db.tweets.find({'user_id' : ac_id, 'created_at': { '$gte': fourteen_days_ago }}))
    for item in tweets:
        data = item.get('text')
        data = data.lower()
        data = data.split()
        flag = 0
        if set(ar1).intersection(data):
            flag = 1
        abc = []
        for x in ar1:
            for y in data:
                    if re.search(x,y):
                        abc.append(x)
                        flag = 1
                        break
        if flag == 1:
            mylist.append(item.get('id'))
            newlist.append(abc)
    print mylist
    print newlist
for i in id_list:
    func(i)
```

This code soen't give me any correct results, and being a noob to regexes, I cannot figure out whats wrong with it. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this job? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first advice - learn regular expressions, it gives you an unlimited power of text processing.

But, to give you some working solution (and start point to further exploration) try this:

```
import re

re_offers = re.compile(r'''
    \b  # Word boundary
        (?:  # Non capturing parenthesis
            deals?  # Deal or deals
            |  # or ...
            offers?  # Offer or offers
            |
            discount
            |
            promotion
            |
            sale
            |
            rs\.?  # rs or rs.
            |
            inr\d+  # INR then digits
            |
            \d+inr  # Digits then INR
        )  # And group
    \b  # Word boundary
    |  # or ...
    \b\d+%  # Digits (1 or more) then percent
    |
    \$\d+\b  # Dollar then digits (didn't care of thousand separator yet)
    ''',
    re.I|re.X)  # Ignore case, verbose format - for you :)

abc = re_offers.findall("e misio $1 is inr123 discount 1INR a 1% and deal")
print(abc)
```

Comment: Am learning Regular expressions, but I need a short-term solution, till I can resolve future such issues on my own. To tell you the truth, I am finding that I am totally pants at regular expressions, and cannot really learn them fast enough

Comment: Try my example and experiment. I think it will solve your problem and you'll not need any `split()`, `lower()` or nested `for`.

Also, if you gave me more info about this "inr" stuff, I could provide better solution for this case.

Comment: Am doing so. And I realized that split() is not needed. INR stands for 'Indian National Rupee.'

Comment: Assumed that it's used 123INR or INR123. Updated example. You probably noted that abc contains matched strings. I think you have all you need to continue, rest is in your hands :)

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Now to learn the dreaded regexes :P

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider starting with `find` instead instead of a regex. You don't have complex expressions, and as you're handling a line of text you don't need to call `split`, instead just use `find`:

```
for token in ar1:
    if data.find(token) != -1:
        abc.append(data)
```

Your for item in tweets loop becomes:

```
for item in tweets:
    data = item.get('text')
    data = data.lower()
    for x in ar1:
        if data.find(x)    
             newlist.append(data)
             mylist.append(item.get('id'))
             break
```

Re: your comment on jonsharpe's post, to avoid including substrings, surround your tokens by spaces, e.g. " rs ", " INR "

Comment: Data is like any tweet thats posted by a stream, including hash-tags, user mentions and others. And you're right about not needing spilt(). I too realized it once I tried jonsharpe's solution.

Comment: Surrounding my tokens with spaces actually can become a very tedious and time-taking job. As the size of the project increases, the company I works for might need to find more and more such tokens. Writing different cases for all of them will be quite a job.

Comment: You could easily automate the task. But the better long-term solution would probably be to go for learning how to compile regular expressions.

Comment: That is something I realized. But in the meanwhile, I am just looking for something short-term.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regular expression for this, you can use `any`:

```
if any(term in tweet for term in search_terms):
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I just wanted to ask you something else, to add to the problem. As you can see, things like "rs" or "Rs" can have so many ways of being written. A word like INR can be a substring in a longer string. To resolve such issues, I think regexes might be needed.

Comment: to avoid including substrings, surround your tokens by spaces, e.g. " rs ", " INR ".

Comment: I would make everything `lower()` (`tweet` *and* `term`) to get around that. `in` will find e.g. `"inr" in "for saleinr250"` without any problems (indeed, you may have problems with it finding too much, e.g. `"inr" in "inroads"`).

Answer (score 1):

In your array of things to search for you don't have a comma between " offers " and "discount" which is causing them to be joined together.

Also when you use split you are getting rid of the whitespace in your input text. "I have a deal" will become ["I","have","a","deal"] but your search terms almost all contain whitespace. So remove the spaces from your search terms in array ar1.

However you might want to avoid using regular expressions and just use in instead (you will still need the chnages I suggest above though):

```
    if x in y:
```